# Data structure that will hold an unknown length of strings and have the ability to remove them later

Tags: c, arrays, memory, data-structures, dynamic-memory-allocation

What's the best data structure for storing an unknown amount of values then removing many?

I'm reading a file and each line is stored as a C string in some larger data structure. Each line is probably less than 20 characters long and one example file has 300000 lines. Whatever data structures I'm going to use will only grow in size at it's initial creation; from there it will only shrink in size. What would I use? In Java I would use Array List or maybe Vector. Could a dynamic array work and if yes how would it look like?

```
char aLine[21];
char *data = malloc(aLine);
fp = fopen("datafile", "r");
if(fp== NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
while(fscanf(fp, "%20s", aLine) == 1)
{
    data = aLine;
    realloc(data, sizeof(data)+sizeof(aLine));
}
```

I want to use standard C and POSIX features so if having lists means usings a third party library I don't think that's an option.

EDIT: well creating a linked list isn't exactly trivial, what's the second best option?

Comment: I think linked list would be a better option.

Comment: @haccks does C come with linked lists?

Comment: @Celeritas Nah, but it comes with structs and pointers.

Comment: What do you mean by *third party* library?

Comment: @haccks let me put it this way: how can I use a linkedlist in c without creating one from the ground up by myself?

Comment: You must have to create before using it. There is no standard function in C to use for linked list.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). You have to [create a linked list](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24684/How-to-create-Linked-list-using-C-C) with the help of pointers and structures.